# liferay p_p_lifecycle change render

Tags: liferay, render, portlet

could you please help?
use liferay 6.1;

the case is:
several portlets on the page(search, login and others portlets). 
jsession is timeout. 
try to search, go to login page. 
But: url is
en/start?p_p_state=normal&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_id=Search_WAR_INSTANCE_1x2x&p_l_id=10715&p_auth=lYs61bin&p_p_mode=view&p_v_l_s_g_id=0

and error from search portlet ("you do not have permission to access" ).
If i set p_p_lifecycle=0 -> no error.

Question is How to change the  p_p_lifecycle.
thank you a lot

Comment: Please try to make sense of your question and try to format the question so that it is understandable. I can't seem to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Lifecycle param is used to specify which method phase of the portlet has to be called, so which method will be called.
0 is for render, 1 for processAction, 2 for serveResource.
If you use a JSP with liferay-portlet taglib, you can change the Lifecycle by calling :

- renderURL for render method;
- actionURL for processAction method;
- resourceURL for serveResource method.

For example :

```
<liferay-portlet:actionURL var="myUrl">
</liferay-portlet:actionURL>
```

This code will create an URL to your processAction (lifecycle=1) in a variable called "myUrl". You can use this URL like that, for example :

```
<aui:form action="${myUrl}" method="post">...</aui:form>
```

Hope it helps you.

Leo